# Python binary path in pip

Tags: xubuntu, python, python3, pip, binary

When I run `python` it runs version 3.10.4:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.4 (main, Apr  8 2022, 17:35:13) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[12]+  Stopped                 python
```

When I run `python3` it runs version 3.8.10:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[13]+  Stopped                 python3
```

`pip` is using `python3`:

```
$ head -n1 /usr//bin/pip
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

How can I change the `python` path in `pip` to use `python` as below?

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to use `pip` is to invoke it like `<python_interpreter> -m pip ...`. That way, you have full control over which python installation the package gets installed/updated/removed for.

You *could* change which version `python3` resolves to, but that's a really bad idea. Ubuntu depends on the default python installation (3.8 in this case), so changing this would break the OS itself and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: so python3.10 -m pip install .....?

Comment: Or just python in your case, since that's what you're telling us you want to install the package(s) for